# Swift: Cannot Override with a stored property and 'required' initializer 'init(coder:)' must be provided by subclass for 'UIViewController'

Tags: swift, xcode6, xcode6.1

I have the code below:

```
import UIKit

class tabBarVC: UIViewController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    var tabBarController : UITabBarController // ERROR1:  Cannot override with a stored property 'tabBarController'

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.tabBarController = UITabBarController()

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() { //ERROR2:  'required' initializer 'init(coder:)' must be provided by subclass for 'UIViewController' 
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

I need to define and initialize a variable called `tabBarController` that can be accessed as `self.tabBarController`.

I'm getting two errors by Xcode:

1. Cannot override with a stored property **`tabBarController`**
2. 'required' initializer `init(coder:)` must be provided by subclass for `UIViewController`

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT **

```
import UIKit

class tabBarVC: UIViewController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    var tabBarController : UITabBarController() // Error: "Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'"

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are loading this VIewController from a storyboard or a nib you will need to change the `required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` to call the superclass declaration, `super.init(coder: aDecoder)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are not assigning anything specific to `tabBarController`, you can just do:

```
 var tabBarController = UITabBarController()
```

and not mention it in the init method.

For error 2 you just need to follow what it says and add `init(coder:)` because you are subclassing that class without a designated initializer.

Comment: when I do 'var tabBarController = UITabBarController()' I get an error, "Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'

Comment: And you are putting it OUTSIDE the init() method? var tabBarController = UITabBarController()

Comment: I did an edit to the question that shows the exact code.

Comment: Oh I see you just need to replace the : with =

Comment: Should be: var tabBarController = UITabBarController() Not: with :

Answer (score 2):

Just rename tabBarController to eg. myTabBarController.

Regarding the required init: Just click the red dot left until it suggests to insert additional code and let it do that.

The better way would be to use `awakeFromNib` instead of the init.